# Datatable binds only half of the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to bind data to a jQuery Datatable but it only binds half of it. I checked the AJAX call; it returns success and I am getting data properly. However the same data is not binding to the grid.

My data:

```js
{
  "draw": "1",
  "recordsFiltered": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1,
  "data": [{
    "TitleName": "w",
    "CustomerName": "q",
    "ServiceType": "r",
    "MailClass": "w",
    "ProcessingCategory": "a",
    "Origin": "a",
    "IsActive": true,
    "DateModified": "1/31/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "ContentTitleId ": 1,
    "MailClassId ": 1,
    "ProcessingCategoryId ": 1,
    "ServiceTypeId ": 1,
    "TransportationTypeId ": 1
  }]
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "/ContentTitleManagement/OverviewPageWithServerSidePagination",
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "json",
      // success: function (result) {
      //   console.log("something");
      // }
    },
    columns: [
      { "data": "TitleName" },
      { "data": "CustomerName" },
      { "data": "ServiceType" },
      { "data": "MailClass" },
      { "data": "ProcessingCategory" },
      { "data": "Origin" },
      { "data": "DateModified" },
      { "data": "IsActive" }, 
      // Data gets bound up to here
      // { "data": "ContentTitleId" },
      // { "data": "MailClassId" },
      // { "data": "ProcessingCategoryId" },
      // { "data": "ServiceTypeId" },
      // { "data": "TransportationTypeId" }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>TITLE NAME</th>
      <th>CUSTOMER NAME</th>
      <th>SERVICE<br />TYPE</th>
      <th>MAIL<br />CLASS</th>
      <th>PROCESSING<br />CATEGORY</th>
      <th>ORIGIN</th>
      <th>DATE<br />MODIFIED</th>
      <th>IS<br />ACTIVE</th>
      <th>Content Title Id</th>
      <th>Mail Class Id</th>
      <th>Processing Category Id</th>
      <th>Service Type Id</th>
      <th>Transportation Type Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The above code works file as long as I keep those columns commented in `columns` section of the `datatable` method. But if I uncomment then it throws below error

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: The URL that the error links to tells you all you need to know: `This occurs when jQuery falls into its error callback handler (this callback built into DataTables), which will typically occur when the server responds with anything other than a 2xx HTTP status code.` Your AJAX request is causing a server-side error. You need to debug why that is happening

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is no server side error. Cause I getting the data if I make a call to the URL http://localhost:8309/ContentTitleManagement/OverviewPageWithServerSidePagination

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and I can still bind the half of the data with commented out columns. It cause problem only when I uncomment those columns

Comment: Then are you sure the error you've included in the question is produced by your current code or a cached version of it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tried running in incognito mode and even I clean the browser before I ran. + what I found is if I uncomment those columns the script does not even make the ajax call. But I see the js is correct.

Comment: You have whitespaces in response, exactly in those commented out fields.

Comment: @yvoytovych yes thanks, now I have noticed that too

Comment: @yvoytovych well, actual output json does not have those whitespaces

Comment: just tried your example in jsfiddle and it works, double check your response
http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/17/

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your 5 last identifiers in data:

```
"IsActive": true,
"DateModified": "1/31/2018 12:00:00 AM",
"ContentTitleId ": 1,  <-- space at the end
"MailClassId ": 1,
"ProcessingCategoryId ": 1,
"ServiceTypeId ": 1,
"TransportationTypeId ": 1
```

You have to change it to:

```
"IsActive": true,
"DateModified": "1/31/2018 12:00:00 AM",
"ContentTitleId": 1,
"MailClassId": 1,
"ProcessingCategoryId": 1,
"ServiceTypeId": 1,
"TransportationTypeId": 1
```